# Email Newsletter HTML: Table Cellspacing in Gmail Viewed in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, html-email, cellspacing

I just realized while checking around, the `<table cellspacing='10'> </table>` doesn't work when I view my gmail in IE (I am using IE9).

But using FF or Chrome, its fine. I use my IE to view my Hotmail and Yahoo account that has the same newsletter, it has cellspacing just fine, so what happens to my IE when viewing my gmail acccount newsletter? Any clue?

Comment: sorry about that. I have reviewed all my questions and answers.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the case having tested in Litmus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add style="border-collapse: separate;" to the  tag, it works in Gmail in IE. Still working on getting it to work in Outlook 2007/2010, haven't had the same luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think border-collapse works any more. Wasn't working for me in IE10 gmail. What ended up working was removing the cellspacing from the table and adding padding directly to the td elements.

Out with the old:

```
<table cellspacing="10"><tr><td>...
```

In with the new:

```
<table><tr><td style="padding:10px">...
```

Comment: padding is not supported by outlook any some other mailbox - I never use padding in email.

Comment: Give it a go on your tds, checked in litmus and email on acid, no trouble. There is said to be an issue with outlook2007 and 10 where px are displayed as points in padding but I've never seen any issues from it.